# Create custom formatter for logging in Quarkus

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

I have a problem with logs displayed in Splunk. Every exception element stack trace being splitted into separated log. Unfortunately I don't have access to Splunk config files so I need to figure something else. I found some info about Quarkus extensions but I'm not sure if it's right direction. Is it possible to create such extension which will allow to modify formatter (for example %e) and replace new line signs with empty spaces (Display whole stack trace in one line) or it can be achieved in a different way? I've search for something similar but no luck. Custom format log which im using below.

```
quarkus.log.console.format=%p %d [%t] app=${app.name} ver=${app.version} cl=%c : %s%e%n
```